# Fetch data in redux reducer and action - how to do it

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have problem to find out how to replace my fetch function into my action and reducer. Here is how does it look like without redux

```
async getData() {
    const amount = this.props.amount;
    if (amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        await fetch(
          `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.props.base}`,
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            const date = data.date;
            const result = (data.rates[this.props.convertTo] * amount).toFixed(
              4,
            );
            this.setState({
              result,
              date,
            });
          }, 3000);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    }
  }
```

How should look action or reducer or both in redux to get the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

Redux doesn't allow you to do api calls in actions or reducers. Instead, you can use libraries like [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/), [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). I personally recommend redux-observable.

If you still want to try doing it on your own, you'll have to create three actions - one for request, one for api call success and one for failure. You can write the same code and instead of `setState` dispatch appropriate actions before and after the call resolves.

Comment: well thank you for information. I still need a code how does will look this function as a reducer and action :(. I'll use redux-thunk

Comment: Take a look at the snippet at the end of this article https://medium.com/@colinlmcdonald/basic-api-call-in-react-with-redux-and-intro-to-thunk-middleware-bd5244cef180

Comment: The official docs for redux also explain async actions using thunk, although it's a longer read. See if you can get into it https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/